# Select more than one item by index position in a M / PowerQuery list?

Tags: powerquery

Let's say I have the following list in M language: `{"A", "B", "C" }` and I want to select more than one item. How can I do it? When I check the M language specs it only shows examples on how to select one item through the following syntax `{list}{#index}` but that only retrieves a single item. I tried using the `:` operator as in other languages without success.

Comment: For contiguous elements you can use `List.Range`.  For non-contiguous elements see this **custom function** [List.SelectPositions](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/01/24/list-selectpositions-in-power-bi-and-power-query/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull specific items in the list like this, position 2,1,4

```
= List.Combine ({ {{list}{2}}, {{list}{1}}, {{list}{4}} })
```

Or you could pick a range with List.Range see [List.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-range)

Or pick out one of the other List.xxx functions in [list functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Power Query doesn't support this with a single function. But you can make your own logic.

The basic pattern is:

```
List.Transform( 
  { 0, 2 },  
  each {1..100}{ _ } 
)
```

The starting list is a list from 1 to 100 represented by {1..100}.

We retrieve the first (index=0) and third (index = 2) item with above code.

You can find the above code turned into a function at his URL: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/select-items-by-position-in-list/

There's also 2 alternative methods in case you want to look at another.

Cheers,
Rick

https://powerquery.how/